# Using an if statement in JS with custom parameter

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make it so that when someone types !familyfortunes %NAME% in message that it will run with the command and take the parameter (%NAME%) from the message and then store it in a variable.

I thought I could use  `if(message.toLowerCase.indexOf("!familyfortunes") !=-1){}` and store $message into another variable but split to remove !familyfortunes so it only kept the username but that keeps returning the error:

> greatbritishbg: !familyfortunes lol [10:53:39] error  - TypeError:
>   undefined is not a function
>       at null. (example.js:68:29)

Which is the `.split()` part.

```
client.addListener('chat', function (channel, user, message) {
    console.log(user.username + ': ' + message);
    if (message.toLowerCase() === '!familyfortunes') { //If message contains !familyfortunes
        //var res = messageString.split("familyfortunes ");// Remove Family Fortunes to just get username
        client.say(channel, 'Latest Follower: ' + Follower.response);
        var raidName = Follower.response;
        io.emit('follow', raidName);
    }
}
```

Any advice on how I can tackle this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. Note that `toLowerCase` is a function, so you'll
need to do `message.toLowerCase().indexOf()`.
I dont know if the message must start with the command or not, but I assume that it has to. Quick example:

```
var msg = "!familyfortunes param1 param2";
if (msg.toLowerCase().indexOf("!familyfortunes") == 0) {
    var parts = msg.split(" ");
    if(parts.length > 1) {
        parts.shift();
        console.log(parts.join(" "));
    }
}
```

`var parts = msg.split(" ")` splits the string on space and return an array.
`msg.shift()` removes the first entry in the array(!familyfortunes), and then `msg.join(" ")` take the remaining parts of the array and build a string, separated by a space.

If you only allow **one** value after the keyword, you can check for `parts.lenght == 2` and just do `console.log(parts[1])` to get the parameter.

Comment: hey @msfoster thanks for that, been looking at documentation and wondering for a while. With regards to the param1 and param2 I assume it uses the spaces to differentiate the different parameters? (Just trying to fully understand before I go ahead and use it)

Answer (score 1):

You should try with a regexp

```
var r =/!familyfortunes\s+(.*)/i
var message = "!familyfortunes %NAME%"
message.match(r)
>> ["!familyfortunes %NAME%", "%NAME%"]
```

the regex match a string starting with !familyfortunes, one or ore spaces and then the argument of the command. The first group is the argument of the command.